# Azure pipeline won't create a prerelease version

Tags: nuget, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have the following code in my pipeline:
The

```
steps:
  - script: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=suffix] --version-suffix alpha'
    displayName: "Stting suffix variable if not master"
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))

  - script: dotnet pack ./myproj.csproj -p:Version=$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(patchVersion).0 --configuration $(buildConfiguration) $(suffix) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    displayName: "Pack mypack"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish NuGet"
    inputs:
      pathtoPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
      artifactName: "Nuget"

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Publish Artifact"
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'myfeed'
      versioningScheme: 'off'
```

The pipeline finishes with no errors and I can see the following in the logs

> dotnet pack ./myproj.csproj -p:Version=0.0.12.0 --configuration
>   Release  --version-suffix alpha --output /home/vsts/work/1/a

However, when looking at the nuget package in the artifacts or in my Visual studio, it is not a prerelease, but a normal nuget. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What's that mean for `prerelease` here? Do you mean the `Prerelease` view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are talking about the [Views on Azure DevOps Services feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/views?view=azure-devops)
Please note that on package creation, it will automatically publish packages back to the **@local** view of your feed. So, it's the expected behavior in your scenario.

> **@local** view contains all packages published directly to the feed (e.g. by nuget push or npm publish) and all packages saved from
>   upstream sources. If you don't use any other views, @local should be
>   your default view.

However you can Promote your package to the `@prerelease` view after that:

> When a package is ready for early adopters, select that package and
>   its dependency graph and promote it to the @prerelease view.

Please refer to [Promote your package to the correct view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/best-practices?view=azure-devops#promote-your-package-to-the-correct-view) for details.

**UPDATE:**

If you mean the suffix `alpha` is not added in the generated package, then you can integrate the suffix into the `version` parameter: (`--version-suffix alpha` is invalid in the command )

```
  - script: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=suffix]-alpha'
    displayName: "Stting suffix variable if not master"
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))

  - script: dotnet pack ./myproj.csproj -p:Version=$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(patchVersion)$(suffix) --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    displayName: "Pack mypack"
```

To promote the package, you can reference below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused here :) So how should I promote it to the prerelease view? should I change the version to Version=$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(patchVersion).alpha or something else?
When I was searching, I've seen the link you have shared but it is not that clear

Comment: If you mean the suffix `alpha` is not added in the generated package, then you can integrate the suffix into the `version` parameter, similar as `Version=$(majorVersion).$(minorVersion).$(patchVersion).$(suffix)`; If you mean `prerelease` view, then nothing related to the version here, the version you set is just a symbol/tag which marks as nature or quality of change. The packages will be published to the local view first, then you can promote the quality ones to the @prerelease view. Please see the attached screenshot on promoting the packages.

Comment: Thank you very much Andy! I wrongfully assumed the prerelase is the same concept as alpha and beta. By adding the -alpha my nuget is not showing up in my VS unless I check the checkbox for "include prerelease" which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)